# python dictionary for students records

Tags: python-3.x

i am trying to create a program in python 3 where it will ask the user to input the students name(name) and his/hers ID numbers(ID) all in one go separated by comma. Then present all the dictionary values in the following format eg:
Name:John  ID:123
Name:Mary  ID:234
Name:Eve  ID:345
the program will run forever unless the user inputs q to exit

up to now i managed to create the following:

```
addName = raw_input("New Name:")
addid = raw_input("ID:")
dictionary = {}
dictionary[addName] = addid
print('Name: ' + addName + '  ID: ' +  addid)
```

i would like to have the program run continuesly, unless the user enters q to exit. How can i do the input in one line so the user will input its name and then its id, separated by comma?  Also print all Names and IDs that the dictionary contains.

Comment: Use a while loop.

Comment: You must be brand new to programming

Comment: yes i am. Could you show me what do you mean?

Comment: some help please?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/While_loop

Answer (score 0):

Couple months late and I am pretty new to coding myself but here's something I put together that might help. I used a lot of comments throughout the code so you know what I'm attempting to do.

```
# Initilize values
i = 0
StuName = None
ID = None
students = {}

# Loop structure that says "While this is true, do this"
while 1:
    i+=1
    student=input('Enter student name and ID or q to exit: ')

# if the user enters 'q' break out of the loop
    if student=='q':
        break 

    else:

# This line takes "John,123" and splits it on the comma into "John" and "123". 
# It stores these under the variables StuName and ID
        StuName, ID = student.split(',')

# This line updates the "students" dictionary with whatever value "StuName" is and "ID" is
        students.update({StuName:ID})

# This line iterates through the "students" dictionary and prints according to how we say    
for StuName, ID in students.items():

#This line is mostly fancy formatting. the \t is a tab, {} is where your variables (StuName, ID) will go
    print ('Name: {}\tID: {}'.format(StuName, ID))
```